# What database documents is more optimal searching only by key? MongoDB or Couchbase? Why?

Tags: database, mongodb, couchbase

I need to search database documents only by their key, wich database engine would you prefer? MongoDB or Couchbase?

I don't know which is better in this case.

What database is more optimal searching by key?

Comment: Both Mongo and Couchbase can do this pretty easily.  Your decision to pick which one should depend on something other than this.

Comment: but which would be more optimal? Thank you!

Comment: All databases are reasonably good while accessing data by primary key.    Based on your question it  does not matter.

Comment: That depends on all other factors, but _not_ on the simple requirement which appears in your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase employee here,

Here are some reasons why Couchbase might be a better option:

1. Couchbase's SDK is "cluster-aware", which means that just with the key of the document it knows exactly where the document is located, so for a KV use case the SDK will talk directly to the node which has the document (Instead of going to master and then to slave in Mongo's case)
2. Couchbase has a cache layer on the top of the database, so if you need to load the same documents often, they will be automatically cached. (On mongo's case, you might need to use Redis for caching)
3. Couchbase is highly scalable, so you can literally scale to dozens of nodes in a single cluster.
4. It is strong-consistent by default
5. If you ever need to explore your data, Couchbase supports SQL 92 (Select, group by, order, join, sort, etc). The query language is an extension of SQL (https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1)
6. Sharding in Couchbase is transparent for the developer, so scaling out is a very simple operation. (Mongo requires resharding sometimes)

There are some other important factors that should be considered and weren't specified in your question.

Comment: Please, could you tell me some other important factor?